# Why is my scope getting cached?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a scope that looks as follows:

```
scope :top, order('score DESC')
```

It's used as follows in my controller:

```
def top
  @users = User.top
  render "list"
end
```

Now, it seems that this scope is getting cached for no reason at all. If I load the top page, add a user and reload it, the user does not appear in the list.

If I do this however:

```
def top
  @users = User.order('score DESC')
  render "list"
end
```

The results don't get cached. What is happening here? I'm using Ruby 2.0.0 and Rails 4.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found what the problem is! The scope should have been defined as follows:

```
scope :top, order: 'score DESC'
```

Answer (score 6):

I think if you use a lambda, then it should not get cached:

`scope :top, lambda { order('score DESC') }`

But then again, I'm not that familiar with the new Rails 4 scope caching.

Comment: This would probably work too, but my answer is the way it should be -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/18046835/591286

Comment: According to http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope this looks like the correct way - wrap it in a lambda or "stabby syntax". Solved the issue for me.