# Q: active record association is cached. but active record scope is not cached?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a question about active record query cache.

I tested active record query cache with rails console.

Model class is like below.

```
class Catalog < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tickets
end

class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :catalog

  scope :active, -> { where(status: STATUSES[:active]) }
end
```

when first time catalogs.tickets in console, sql executed in console.

when second time catalog.tickets, no sql executed in console.

on the other hands

active is scope for Ticket model.

when first time catalog.tickets.active,  sql executed in console.

when second time also catalog.tickets.active, sql executed in console.

result of scope is not cached in model?

every time sql executed in the case of scope?

Comment: Why don't you go through the guides and check for yourself?

Answer (score 0):

The data isn't cached when using lambda. You can read a lil more here: [Why is my scope getting cached?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18046704/why-is-my-scope-getting-cached)